# Add date time to list without it re ordering the date and time value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, datetime, append

Hey guys I have this user input where after it gets entered it adds it to a list and orders it from latest entry to the one before it and prints it.. What I want to do is with every user entry I want to add the time and date so I know when the input was entered. What happens with it now is it re arranges the date and times entry so the format is not readable in the list. Does anyone know how I can stop this from happening but still be appended to the list with every entry so it's in the right format? Thank you so much

```
from datetime import datetime 

def status():

    all_status_updates = []
    today = datetime.now()
    while True: 
        stat = input("Type Status Update Here...\n")
        if stat != "exit":
            #all_status_updates.append(stat)
            all_status_updates.extend((today, stat))
            print(all_status_updates[::-1])
        elif stat == "exit":
            break

status()
```

Comment: in our current code you set the same date for every entry

Comment: What format are you wanting specifically? You can modify the datetime object using qualifiers like `datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: this worked thank u so much but it is showing the same time for every post anyway to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your code instantiates the datetime outside of the while loop. This means that every time you enter a new string into the input field, it's taking the pre-set datetime instead of making a new one. Simple fix:

```
from datetime import datetime 

def status():

    all_status_updates = []
    while True: 
        stat = input("Type Status Update Here...\n")
        if stat != "exit":
            today = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
            all_status_updates.extend((today, stat))
            print(all_status_updates[::-1])
        elif stat == "exit":
            break

status()
```

I've also added the `.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")` suffix to make the datetime more human-readable. You can change those modifiers around to suit your needs.

Here, in the above code example, the datetime is only called once the user inputs a text string that is not 'exit'. You can also put this into the main body of the while loop but then it's never used most of the time.

Comment: ahh I knew it was somethings so simple thank you so much

Comment: Hey no worries, glad to help. Welcome to SO